# Vue and HTML5 input tag

Tags: html, vue.js

I would like to create HTML5 slider. Something like it:

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" v-bind:value="magnitude_value" step="1" />{{magnitude_value}}
```

But look like `v-bind` do not trigger update `magnitude_value` value, because when when I change slider position I do not see any updates

Answer (score 1):

use v-model instead of v-bind:value

Comment: could you show example of syntax? `v-model:value="magnitude_value"` is it's correct?

Comment: http://codepen.io/jasonma/pen/jVOvwd, v-model:value and v-bind:value does not exist, here is the documentation, https://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Use v-model like this. `magnitude_value` will then be bound to the value of the `input`

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" v-model="magnitude_value" step="1" /> {{magnitude_value}}
```